# Out of memory(Heap Space) error in springboot application on curl call to REST endpoint from shell script

Tags: shell, spring-boot, unix, curl

I have an application that can be divided in the following steps

- Retrieve the data form database
- Formatting the data
- Writing the final output in a file

Following are few details regarding it and its current behavior

- This is a java springboot application.
- It is dealing with more than 2.5 million records and generating a ~500MB file
- The process gets called in two ways

  - **Internal spring scheduling**

    - The internal spring scheduling is there in place and the process gets called automatically in those hours.
    - The process gets completed under **1.5 hours**. In between that more than **1 hours** goes by to retrieve the data. The rest of the time is used for formatting data and writing file.
    - The process completed successfully on every occasion.
  - **REST endpoint**

    - This is used from the **shell script**, which in turn has **curl** call to access this end point. This end point calls the same process as the internal scheduling.
    - This script is run by a different user than the first one.
    - The data retrieval process and formatting worked fine but memory constraints issue while writing to file failed the process on every occasion.
- The differences between the two approaches, so far identified are as below

  - The **user** is different.
  - The first one runs as **java** process itself. Where as the second one follows a chain of processes **bash -> curl -> java**.

I suspect there might be some user and/or process specific memory limitation, which is causing this conflicting behavior. Please suggest.

Comment: Looks like you are reading everythin in memory, do the processing and push it again. Don't read everything in memory instead do little chunks or do a streaming based proces. Reading the entire dataset in memory requires massive amounts of memory and depending on what you do with it it might requires a factor 2 or 3 of the memory you actually need.

Comment: I am really doing everything in memory. But the reason behind that is that I am reading from database view with very poor performance and I don't have control over the query. So I can't make multiple db call as that will cause the process to run forever. The real concern here is that it is behaving differently in the mentioned two cases. I am not able to figure out what is causing that.

Comment: You shouldn't read everything, process, write. What you should be doing is read/process/write at the same time. Don't do everything in memory. I nowhere suggested you should do multiple queries.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. But how exactly you are suggesting I do the read/process/write. I am using Spring data jpa to get data from DB and as a result I get everything together  as list of beans and then I pass that to OpenCsv for writing.

Comment: Write a method that either returns a `Stream` or don't use JPA but SQL directly. At least make sure you are writing a query that only returns what you need (and not 200 fields while you only need 30 of those). When you have a  `Stream` you get a forward reading cursor and you only have a few lines in-memory instead of the whole table. And doing `list.stream()` doesn't count as you then still have everything in-memory.

Comment: I am planning to use the same writer object to write to the file after following read/process/write methodology for say a chunk of data at a time. With the increase in file size is there any effect on the writer or in turn the heap

Comment: If you read/process/write a single element and write directly to disk instead of to memory it doesn't matter if you have 1 or 100000 elements. It scales linearly (more or less). Hence my suggestion to use a stream as it then doesn't really matter anymore.

Comment: I implemented the stream() approach in a proper way as you @M.Deinum suggested and that solved the issue. Thanks for your help.